# Combining client credentials flow with authorization code flow (win-auth)

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, openiddict

I'm currently trying to get Openiddict working in the following scenario:

My resource-API is also the one responsible for hosting the authorize Openiddict stack (so that every API is completely self-contained and not relying on a central IDP).

Multiple client apps are accessing this API with different permissions based on the client app and the user using this client app. So to get this abstract setup a little more clear here is a simple example:

1. Resource-API (this will also host Openiddict): MyApi
2. Client-App: MyClientApp1
3. Client-App: MyClientApp2
4. User: MyUser1
5. User: MyUser2

MyApi will have these example endpoints:

1. OnlyForMyClientApp1
2. OnlyForMyClientApp2
3. OnlyForMyClientApp1AndMyUser1
4. OnlyForMyClientApp1AndMyUser2
5. OnlyForMyClientApp2AndMyUser1
6. OnlyForMayClientApp2AndMyUser2

I get the client credentials flow and the authorization code flow with integrated win-auth up and running by looking at the Openiddict samples, but only on their own and not combined.

But I don't know how I get both flows working in conjunction together.